# How to implement this logic flow?

Tags: logic

ok, here is the story...

I have 3 textfield for user to select....

[textfield A][textfield B][textfield C]

and a confirm button, the user need to add three textfield, after that , the user need to click the confirm button.... but based on different select order, the result is different, for example:
A>B>C, I will show red.
When the user select in this order:
B>A>C I will show green. 
When the user select in this order:
C>B>A I will show the color blue....

based on different user select order, it will show different color.... 
But the question is, when I add more and more textfield, how can I implement this logic?
First, I design to have an array , when the user select one textfield, I store the textfield id to array, when user select the second one, I will store in the array, until the user click confirm, I read back the array to display the color....
But I think it will become very big & messy when more and more textfield is added, any better ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It's sort of a though question because in general there are n!=n*(n-1)*...*1 permutations of n elements. This means that for n=4 you'll have 24 permutations, and for n=5 120...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but what I'd be inclined to do is store the selections in a string that gets appended to each time (starting with empty string of course), trimming to the rightmost x characters. Then you can do a simple switch/case statement to determine the color. For example (C# fragments, sort of):

```
string selectStr = string.Empty;

void Select(string btn) {
  selectStr += btn;
  selectStr = selectStr.Remove(0, btn.Length - 3);
}

void Confirm() {
  switch (selectStr) {
    case "ABC" : /* make red */ break;
    case "BAC" : /* make green */ break;
    // etc.
  }
}
```